# bucles anidados

Tags: python, condiciones, bucles, sql

Tengo una duda, no se si es buena practica anidar bucles `while` con `for` o viceversa.

Un ejemplo de la parte del código:

```py
def update_data(clients):
    dao= DAO()
    listclients(clients)
    exists_id=False
    while not (exists_id):
        client_id=int(input('Enter the ID you want to update: '))    
        for i in clients:
            if i[0] == client_id:
                print(dao.find_client(client_id))
                exists_id=True
                break 
        if not exists_id:
            print('***Id not found***')


    client_first_n= input('Enter new name: ')
    client_last_n= input('Enter new last name: ')
    while True:
        client_dni= input('Enter new DNI: ')
        print("")
        if len(client_dni) == 9:
            break
        else:
            print('***The DNI field cannot have more or less than 9 alphanumeric characters.***')
            print('Please login again\n')
        

    return

    dao.update_client(client_id,client_first_n,client_last_n,client_dni)
```

Es una aplicación de consola CRUD con Python y Mysql.
Todo me funciona perfecto, pero quiero optimizar y saber si es una buena practica o no el anidar estos bucles.

Comment: Técnicamente no hay ningún problema con hacer eso. Ahora, lo que te recomendaría en aras de mejorar la legibilidad, mantenibilidad y organización del código, es que apliques el [extract method](https://qafoo.com/blog/098_extract_method.html#:~:text=Refactoring%20is%20the%20process%20of,explains%20what%20it%20is%20doing.) para reducir el tamaño y anidamiento de la función.

Comment: Ok, muchas gracias.